# How to get all pks after grouping them (finding duplicates)

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have three tables and I am searching for the duplicates in the main table that have the same foreign keys. But I need the primary keys in return of this query:

```
SELECT ta.fk1, ta.fk2, count(ta.fk2)
FROM ta, tb, tc
WHERE ta.fk2 = tb.pk
AND ta.fk1 = tc.pk
GROUP BY ta.fk1, ta.fk2
HAVING count(ta.fk2) > 1
```

How can I get the primary keys? Another join or nested query? I tried all I know and found.
Thanks for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this maybe?

```
select distinct ta_pk, tc_pk
from (
  select ta.pk as ta_pk, 
         tc.pk as tc_pk, 
         count(*) over (partition by ta.fk2) as cnt
  from ta
    join tb on ta.fk2 = tb.pk
    join tc on ta.fk1 = tc.pk
) t
where cnt > 1;
```

Comment: "Find duplicate rows" comes up often enough that we probably need to pick/create an authoritative answer and start closing things as dups.